# How to get an element's full start tag in javascript (not only tagName)?

Tags: javascript

Is there simple any way to get an element's starting tag in javascript as string?
Suppose I have a DOM node which is a html element in a variable, I would like write something similar:

```
var tagName = element.tagName; //Works
var startingTag = element.startingTag; // Is there any way?
var startingTag = getStartingTag(element);  // Or do I have to write my own function?
```

Thx for answers

For example this is a starting tag I would like to get into a string:

```
 <Table class="anyClass" width="100" ... >
```

where the tagName only gives this: "Table"

Comment: Is there a reason you need the full starting tag? To get the attributes? Maybe there's a different way to accomplish what you need

Comment: I need the starting tag as textual information to display in the user interface. I know how to get a specific attribute with DOM

Comment: You could get all the attributes of the element, iterate through them (and their values) and construct the string manually. I don't know how difficult this would be in your situation. Should be right up your alley.

Comment: i dont think there is default support to achieve what you want, you can how ever append a function startingTag to the element object vs building a standalone global function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could do:

```
var elStr    = element.outerHTML
   ,startTag = elStr.substr(0,elStr.indexOf('>')+1);
```

Or use the `element.attributes` if you need information about attributes

Comment: Thx :-). outerHtml somehow got out of my scope, because WebStorm intellisense gave me only innerHtml, which definitely not applicable for this task.

Comment: This doesn't work in cases like `<div onclick="this.innerHTML += '<div></div>'">`

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the attributes and append them to some string.

```
function getStartingTag(elem)
    var str = '',
        attr = elem.attributes,
        value;

    // Beginning of tag. toLowerCase() for a cleaner string.
    str += '<' + elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() + ' ';

    for (var i = 0, l = attr.length; i < l; i++) {

        // Safety check.
        value = attr[i].nodeValue.replace('"', '\\"');

        // Append the name + value of the attribute.
        str += attr[i].nodeName + '="' + attr[i].nodeValue + '" ';
    }
    str += '>';

    return str;
}
```